# How do I automatically specify the RSpec build system in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, osx-mavericks, rspec2

In SublimeText2, using the `Tools > Build System > Automatic` setting, I am not able to run RSpec tests, despite the promise of the RSpec control package, and get an error complaining that the file is not a normal Ruby file.

`/Users/username/Projects/Ruby/filename.spec.rb:4:in '<main>': undefined method 'describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]`

However, if I change the build system setting to `RSpec`, then the test runs fine, but now I can't build any other projects without changing the setting back to `Automatic`.

I'm using the RSpec packages from here: [GitHub/SublimeText/RSpec](https://github.com/SublimeText/RSpec). There's a note indicating the *You must assign the builder for your project to 'Ceedling'*, which I was unfamiliar with, but eventually [found on GitHub](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling).

Considering Seedling is a "build system for C projects", is there an easier way to easily build RSpec test in ST2 without this Seedling dependancy, or manually changing the build system setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like someone else had the same question and [fixed it](https://github.com/osrocha/RSpec/commit/06af0dfc329c66da3d1ede527939729813270f54) in a folk for the control package.

For all those that follow, `SublimeText 2 > Preferences > Browse Packages > RSpec > RSpec.sublime-build`

Change `"selector": "source.ruby",` to `"selector": "source.ruby.rspec",` and make sure the files are titled `filename.rb.rspec`.